# Can we automatically generate jmeter dashboard report with Maven-jmeter plugin with out any manual command

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate jmeter dashboard report from maven. But for generating jmeter dashboard report, we have to fire a command,

**jmeter -g /path/to/jtl/file -o /where/you/want/to/store/dashboard**

But with maven can we do that? what i want is to remove all manual process of copying csv file and run command on local copy of jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via extra [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) task as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-report-dashboard</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <argument>/path/to/ApacheJMeter.jar</argument>
                    <argument>org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver</argument>
                    <argument>-g</argument>
                    <argument>/path/to/results.jtl</argument>
                    <argument>-o</argument>
                    <argument>/path/to/report/folder<argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on different ways of kicking off a JMeter test without using GUI

Comment: Thanks Dmitri,you solved half of my issue, But what should be the "Path to Jmeter.jar". Can I direct it to maven repository?

Comment: Given you Maven project has JMeter jars in its classpath you can go for something like:
    <argument>-classpath</argument>
    </classpath>

Comment: Yes, it worked, when I provided a absolute path of my local apachejmeter.jar (version 3.0). But when I try to give relative path, maven always download 2.13 version of jmeter. And so maven build fails.  What should be my artifactId so that it will download all jmeter 3.0 dependencies . Or should I have to add each seperately.

Comment: I believe you should ask Maven JMeter Plugin developer, I don't have any control of that artifact

Comment: @Dimitri, Yes, I should do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using last version of [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) it will be generated by default configuration.

Sample pom.xml that uses JMeter 3.3:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>training-project</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateReports>true</generateReports>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```